# RESTful way to swap a relationship between 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, updates

I have a User and a Shift. Users have many shifts.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shifts
end

class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

One of my users can't do one of their shifts and so wants to swap it with another user.

What is the best way to do this restfully? It seems that I need to update 2 shifts simultaneously: The shift that needs to be swapped and then then shift that it needs to be swapped with. Therefore, this doesn't really fit with the `edit` and `update` actions which are intended for changing a single model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't fit neatly with any of the default RESTful routes for a single resource (*member* route).  One possibility is to add a new RESTful *collection* route:

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do
  collection do
    post 'swap'
  end
end
```

More at:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Answer (score 1):

```
def change_shift(shift_id_or_object, alt_user)
  shift = Shift.find(shift_id_or_object) unless shift_id_or_object.respond_to? :user
  shift.user = alt_user
  shift
end
```